# Find the Maximum date in an Array (non-LINQ)

Tags: c#

Suppose I have an array of dates

```
DateTime[] dt = new DateTime[10];
// populate array with dates
```

How can I find the maximum date without using LINQ?

Comment: what I tried is using some thing like a bubble sort... notso elegant.

Comment: gold rush!  5 answers in 1 min.. :D how i wish i was a master at smth so i didnT have to join the rabbit race for cheap rep points :/

Comment: You could have used sorting for this, but there already are methods available in the .NET framework to sort arrays, like Array.Sort, you don't need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I notice the OP avoided answering the, "is this homework" question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var maxDate = DateTime.MinValue;
foreach (var date in dt) {
    maxDate = date > maxDate ? date : maxDate;
}
```

You mention using a sorting algorithm, presumably so that you can just ask for:

```
var maxDate = dt[dt.Length - 1];
```

After the array was sorted. The thing is, you'd need to find a sorting algorithm that performs better than *`O(n)`* to gain any advantage.  Bubble Sort is *`O(n^2)`* so there's no point in using it; it performs worse, on average, than just running through the list once.

Answer (score 0):

In the code below i initialise the max date to an 'empty' value, then i loop through the array and update the max date if we don't have one yet, or the one we do have is before the one in the array.

```
DateTime? Max = null;
foreach(var d in dt)
{
    if(Max == null || Max.Value < d)
        Max = d;
}
```

The above deals with an empty array and an actual date of `DateTime.MinValue`

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime maxDate = DateTime.MinValue;

foreach (DateTime date in dt
{
    if (date > maxDate)
    {
        maxDate = date;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution which uses sorting (modifies the array so that it becomes sorted):

```
Array.Sort(dt);
DateTime maxValue = dt[dt.Length - 1];
```