# what's wrong with this code (.net 2.0)

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, .net-2.0

I am trying to get latest date using code below, but it goes into infinte loop and displays nothing in console,

```
    public static void sortsortyMyDates()
    {
        int i = 1;
        DateTime[] dtList = new DateTime[20];
        DateTime LatestDate = dtList[1];

        dtList[1] = Convert.ToDateTime("28/05/2013 13:00:00");
        dtList[2] = Convert.ToDateTime("23/04/2013 13:00:00");
        dtList[3] = Convert.ToDateTime("25/03/2013 13:00:00");
        dtList[4] = Convert.ToDateTime("08/04/2013 13:00:00");

        while(i < dtList.Length)
        {
            int result = DateTime.Compare(LatestDate, dtList[i]);

            if (result < 0)
                continue;
            else
                LatestDate = dtList[i];

            ++i;
        }

        Console.WriteLine(LatestDate.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: Define "not working", take a look at `Max()`.

Comment: it displays nothing, like in countless loop

Comment: Is this an exam? I'm confused.

Comment: What are you trying to do and where does the web service fit in here ?

Comment: I am trying to get latest date

Comment: Why not use Linq Max()?

Comment: Just an aside; You do know that C arrays are zero based right? Also I'm not sure that LatestDate is properly initialized... It could be but you are attempting to initalize it with an unitialized element of the array. DateTime is a data type and not a reference type

Comment: Good point about 2.0. Why not update? 2.0 is massively out of date nowadays. Finding the max date in an array has been answered already. http://stackoverflow.com/q/8990268/20048 for example.

Comment: @Simon I agree but I can't force my boss can I

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a problem with your loop logic:

```
if (result < 0)
    continue;
```

If `result < 0` then you don't increment `i`, and so the loop doesn't progress.

Also, your comparison is the wrong way around.  `result < 0` would mean that the currently-tested date is later than the current maximum.  The reason you're getting `01/01/0001` as an output is because you're current code actually finds the *earliest* date, and most of your array is unintialised (and therefore a lot earlier than your test values!).

Switch your `if` to this instead (and remove the `else` entirely):

```
if (result < 0)
    LatestDate = dtList[i];
```

Comment: output now is       01/01/0001  00:00:00

Comment: That is because you initialize it with dtList[1] before having assigned dtList[1] a value. Ergo it will default to DateTime.Min

Comment: I put it after initialize, but still same result

Answer (score 2):

If `continue` is executed, `i` is no longer incremented, and the loop will not terminate.